# Read and combine multiple csv files with different columns

Tags: python, excel

I just want to ask of how are you going to combine multiple csv files with different columns. Not all csv files have the same number of columns and column names. The condition is if I want to keep the all the columns. So for example, in dataframe1 there is column A,B and C. In dataframe2 there is column B,C and D and in dataframe 3 there is column C,D and E. I want my output to be have all the columns and it will register Null value for those dataframes that not contains the columns of the other dataframes. In this situation I was also converting minute to hour data.

Thanks in advance

Al Sah-Him

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5eHG.jpg)

filepath=os.listdir(ndr)
    print(filepath)

```
li=[]


for f in filepath:
    data=pd.read_csv(f, header=0)
    data['collectiondatetime']= pd.to_datetime(data['collectiondatetime'])
    groupref=pd.to_datetime(data['collectiondatetime'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H'))
    frame=data.groupby(groupref).mean()
    print(frame)
    li.append(frame)

df=pd.concat(li, sort=False)
print(df)
```

Comment: do  your columns have the same name in each csv? I would have a list of the column names you want to keep `col=['a`,'b','c']` (or some mapping to normalize them), then only keep those columns like: `df1 = df[['a','c']]` and return that to your list of dataframes

Comment: Hi. each csv file has many columns. I think it was almost 70 csv files with 500+ columns and 200k rows because it is on minute data.